# Is there any reason to fight enemies in Chapters 1-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I watched my brother playing FFXIII and he explained how there were no character levels, only the Crystarium. So when I started a new game, before the Crystarium tutorial there was no mention of CP and I assume I wasn't earning any. I actually felt like I wasn't getting anything from these battles.

Is there any reason to fight these early monsters? Are they tied to some hidden achievement/trophy down the line?

EDIT: The question was initially about Chapter 1, but it should also apply to Chapter 2 where you still get no CP and enemies are more easily avoidable.

Comment: After playing and researching some more, it seems that Chapter 2 is the best place for obtaining Deceptisol and Fortisol shrouds (http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/928790-final-fantasy-xiii/faqs/67989), but to most gamers this isn't important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some enemies that can't be avoided, and some that are scripted, so those have to be fought. Others can be avoided (with some luck and skill) but no, they don't *have* to be fought.

However, being the tutorial level, they really are just there so you can get some practice in with using the combat system, and if I remember correctly, they do give you Gil and a chance at getting materials, depending on your performance.

Comment: Though the gil amount is pretty small and the items are kind of weak and available from shops later.  On recent play-throughs I just skip everything I can in chapters 1-2.

Comment: At later chapters (I think ~9?) it's possible to farm high-level materials and extreme amounts of gil and exp. During my playthrough, I had rarely any issues with fights until the later chapters, and I skipped most of the optional fights.

Answer (score 3):

In chapter 1 there are 4 required fights, and no treasures worth fighting to get. The enemies drop phoenix downs and potions and some fang components so nothing special.

In chapter 2 you can farm sols from the ghouls which are quite useful. The items worth getting are the Gladius and the Power Wristband. Otherwise dodging everything there is fine as well. Ghouls also drop Cieth Tears and Tears of Frustration, these components are quite good for early game leveling. So by farming ghouls you get sols and good components. It won't make a difference long term. But if you want to be OP early game, chapter 2 isn't a bad place to farm.

You might ask, why not delay farming to chapter 3 where you can also earn CP from battles. First the rate of sol drops halves in ch3, so you will be receiving fewer sols. The enemies are tougher and more spread out and there is no good place to respawn enemies easily. Also because of the crystarium system each area has a CP cap, so CP farming is essentially pointless. Farming components for upgrades will make you much stronger than farming CP in early game.

Comment: Did you say "Phoenix Down" and "nothing special" in the same sentence?!

Comment: I just mean that PDs are only 1000 gil. So they are incredibly cheap once you are out of early game. And potions are even cheaper 50 gil. You really shouldn't ever die with potions and/or medics. So the PDs should essentially be unused. In fact I sell all but 1 for the early game gil. And anyway if you die, you can just reset the fight and try again. PDs are basically useless in casual play.